# Why doesn't script load when <script> moved from body to the head?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

jS novice here. Here are 2 almost identical html's. The top one works, the bottom one doesn't for some reason (moved 2 `<script>` columns from body to head). Why doesn't the one with all `<script>`'s in the `<head>` work? This one works:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="center">
    <a class="fancybox" href="imagelarge.jpg"><img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

This one doesn't:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="center">
    <a class="fancybox" href="imagelarge.jpg"><img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></a>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try validating your page first and find possible nonclosed tags. Also, it seems that you are using HTML5 tags without a HTML5 `DOCTYPE`

Comment: both pass at validator.w3.org. Updated OP with both's full html to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

first of all the script include could always be in the header

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
</head>
```

And now.. fancapps themselfes put the onload part directly under the images they want to add a fancybox to. So this might have a reason -at least for their demo page-  but I think it should be possible to just drop the document.ready part and give it a shot.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});</script>
```

so you end up with:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

If I'm correct this slightly changes the order of execution, the function will be called after the page is not only fully loaded but fully parsed too, so that fancybox is called AFTER the fancybox class is assigned to the img-link

Comment: it doesn't really matter, you can place your custom fancybox script just after loading the js plugin files AND BEFORE the html code since you are using `$(function(){...});`, which will make the script to wait until the DOM is ready.

Comment: well.. it SHOULDN'T really matter, yes, that's why i used `$(function(){...});` unfortunately I do have a plugin that requires even that code to be directly after the container it should mofify. And since I didn't test that with fancybox thoroughy, I added "If I'm correct..."

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference between the two versions, except that the bottom code doesn't include the jquery.js script tag before the jquery.fancybox.pack.js. Everything will work once it does.

Comment: These are questions, not answers.

Comment: this should be in the comments area... this is not an answer

Comment: The above should be as comments, not an answer

Comment: Yes, the version with the fancybox in <body> includes .jquery.js (that is the head). That is the script that works tho. The one that doesn't has everything in the <head>. I'll make a fiddle in a sec.

Comment: Really not that much of an improvement. The "bottom code" is the one that OP has described as working. OP is showing the code that is being moved. The jquery script is still there.